# Unable to load en_core_web_trf in spacy

Tags: spacy

Receive "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'full'" when attempt to load en_core_web_trf.

Full error below. I can successfully load en_core_web_sm, and have run, running spacy 3.4.2.

```
    !python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```

```
    nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')
```

error:

```
     30 def load(
     31     name: Union[str, Path],
     32     *,
   (...)
     37     config: Union[Dict[str, Any], Config] = util.SimpleFrozenDict(),
     38 ) -> Language:
     39     """Load a spaCy model from an installed package or a local path.
     40 
     41     name (str): Package name or model path.
   (...)
     52     RETURNS (Language): The loaded nlp object.
     53     """
---> 54     return util.load_model(
     55         name,
     56         vocab=vocab,
     57         disable=disable,
     58         enable=enable,
     59         exclude=exclude,
     60         config=config,
...
---> 54 self._growth_tracker = torch.full((1,), 0, dtype=torch.int)
     55 self._scale = torch.full((1,), init_scale)
     56 self._found_inf = False
```

followed this [question](https://www.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69406767/cant-load-spacy-en-core-web-trf.com/) but doesnt seem to work

Comment: Which OS are you using? Are you using your GPU or CPU alone? Are you using a virtual environment? Did you use `pip` or `conda`? Before installing `en_core_web_trf`, you should have installed `spacy` with something like `pip install spacy[transformers]==3.4.2`, was that the case?

Comment: Thanks @DavidEspinosa. In the end i dont know the cause, i uninstalled and reinstalled and all working

Comment: Glad to know that _"the good ol' reboot"_ saved the day for you @BD98 ;)